# SQL query for Join statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables **products**, **pricingGroup** and **productPricing**. I want to show all products even it has no service pricing and set its status/IsActive to false.

**What query I have now**

```
SELECT product.productId, 
       products.ProductCode, 
       product.ProductDetails, 
       product.ProductDescription,
       (CASE WHEN prgrp.pricingGroupId IS NOT NULL && product.IsActive = 1 THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 END) IsActive, 
       prgrp.PricingName,
       pricing.amount 
FROM Products product
LEFT OUTER JOIN productPricing AS pricing ON product.productId = pricing.productId OR pricing.productId IS NULLL
LEFT OUTER JOIN pricingGroup as prgrp on true
```

**What I want to Get**

```
ProductId    ProductCode  ProductDetails  ProductDescrition  IsActive   PricingGroupName  Amount
1            PRCD1        detail1         Descrition1        1          MERCHANT          20
1            PRCD1        detail1         Descrition1        0          Consumer          20
1            PRCD1        detail1         Descrition1        0          OTHERS            20
2            PRCD2        detail2         Descrition2        1          Consumer          25
2            PRCD2        detail2         Descrition2        0          MERCHANT          25
2            PRCD2        detail2         Descrition2        0          OTHERS            25
3            PRCD3        detail3         Descrition3        0          Consumer          0
3            PRCD3        detail3         Descrition3        0          MERCHANT          0
3            PRCD3        detail3         Descrition3        0          OTHERS            0
```

**Products Table**

```
ProductId    ProductCode  ProductDetails  ProductDescrition  IsActive
1            PRCD1        detail1         Descrition1        1
2            PRCD2        detail2         Descrition2        1
3            PRCD3        detail3         Descrition3        0
```

---

**ProductPricing Table**

```
ProductPricingId    PricingGroup  ProductId  Amount  Fee
1                   1             1          20      5
2                   1             2          25      5
```

---

**PricingGroup Table**

```
PricingGroupId    PricingName  
1                 Merchant       
2                 Consumer
3                 Others
```

---

Comment: So what is wrong with your query? what is not working?

Comment: I see a lot of typo error, `product` instead of `products`. `description`

Comment: yes it's not working the way I want. the status copy of the original status of product.

Comment: I already edit it sorry about the TypeO.

Comment: What is the rule for the amount in your result set, your sample suggest that merchant price should be displayed but what if merchant and consumer are both available what then should others be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are missing last join clause `pricing.PricingGroup = prgrp.PricingGroupId`.
- You don't need `OR products.productId IS NULL` because that is primary key of `Products` table and will not be null.

```
SELECT product.ProductId, 
    product.ProductCode, 
    product.ProductDetails, 
    product.ProductDescription,
    IF(pricing.ProductId = product.ProductId && product.IsActive = 1, 1, 0) IsActive, 
    prgrp.PricingName, 
    pricing.amount 
FROM Products product
JOIN pricingGroup as prgrp
LEFT JOIN productPricing AS pricing ON pricing.PricingGroup = prgrp.PricingGroupId && pricing.productId = product.productId;
```

Comment: I already edit the sample. the problem about the last join clause is if there's no productId in ProductPricing it doesn't display.

Comment: SELECT product.productId, 
    product.ProductCode, 
    product.ProductDetails, 
    product.ProductDescription,
    (CASE WHEN prgrp.pricingGroupId IS NOT NULL && product.IsActive = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) IsActive, 
    prgrp.PricingName, 
    pricing.amount 
FROM Products product
LEFT JOIN productPricing AS pricing ON 1 = 1
LEFT JOIN pricingGroup as prgrp on pricing.PricingGroup = prgrp.PricingGroupId;

Comment: FYI i don't test that

Comment: thank for the solutions, but the problem with this is the status/IsActive. If the product doesn't exist in pricing table the status must be false - 0.product and pricing has 1 to many relationship so i can different pricing per product.

Comment: I also add this in the last join `pricing.productId = product.productId` for faster results. hehe

Answer (score 0):

If you are on version 8 or above you could cross join in a cte to get all the possible pricing groups for a product and then left join to productpricing

```
 with cte as
(select p.*,pg.*
from products p
cross join pricinggroup pg
)
select cte.productid,cte.productcode,cte.productdetails,cte.productdescription,
         case when pricinggroup is null then 0 else isactive end as isactive,
         pp.*
from cte
left join productpricing pp on pp.pricinggroup = cte.pricinggroupid and cte.productid = pp.productid
order by cte.productid,cte.pricinggroupid ;

+-----------+-------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+------------------+--------------+-----------+--------+------+
| ProductId | ProductCode | ProductDetails | ProductDescription | isactive | ProductPricingId | PricingGroup | ProductId | Amount | Fee  |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+------------------+--------------+-----------+--------+------+
|         1 | PRCD1       | detail1        | Descrition1        |        1 |                1 |            1 |         1 |     20 |    5 |
|         1 | PRCD1       | detail1        | Descrition1        |        0 |             NULL |         NULL |      NULL |   NULL | NULL |
|         1 | PRCD1       | detail1        | Descrition1        |        0 |             NULL |         NULL |      NULL |   NULL | NULL |
|         2 | PRCD2       | detail2        | Descrition2        |        0 |                2 |            1 |         2 |     25 |    5 |
|         2 | PRCD2       | detail2        | Descrition2        |        0 |             NULL |         NULL |      NULL |   NULL | NULL |
|         2 | PRCD2       | detail2        | Descrition2        |        0 |             NULL |         NULL |      NULL |   NULL | NULL |
|         3 | PRCD3       | detail3        | Descrition3        |        0 |             NULL |         NULL |      NULL |   NULL | NULL |
|         3 | PRCD3       | detail3        | Descrition3        |        0 |             NULL |         NULL |      NULL |   NULL | NULL |
|         3 | PRCD3       | detail3        | Descrition3        |        0 |             NULL |         NULL |      NULL |   NULL | NULL |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+------------------+--------------+-----------+--------+------+
9 rows in set (0.014 sec)
```

I don't know the rule for deriving amount for null groups so have left as null

Comment: Hi, the problem with this is the IsActive/status. In PRCD1 the status/IsActive of group Consumer and others should be false.

Comment: The Product is active irrespective of whether it has a product group or not, do you simply want to override this if there is not a product group? If so see edit

Comment: this also work with Mysql8, and also I add IFNULL for the default value 0. thank you